# How to guarantee the order of transactions in MetaMask?

Tags: transactions, metamask, json-rpc, transaction-propagation

I create my transactions with [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/) and push them into an array like this:

```js
const promises = [];
promises.push(createTokenApprovalTx());
promises.push(createFooTx());
```

It's important that the token approval transaction is signed and submitted before the foo transaction, because the latter moves tokens around. Therefore, I order them properly and set a higher nonce on the foo transaction.

I then submit them like this:

```js
const txs = await Promise.all(promises);
await Promise.all(
  txs.map(tx => {
    return tx.wait(1);
  }),
);
```

The catch is that the order is **not** guaranteed. Sometimes, roughly 3 in 4 times, it is indeed the case that the token approval comes first, but not all the time.

How to accomplish this with MetaMask or, generally, with any JSON-RPC provider?

Comment: You can always chain promises: `createTokenApprovalTx().then(() => createFooTx())`. The user is in total control of Metamask and he can reorder them.

Comment: Or on your `createTokenApprovaTx()` and `createFooTx()` build the tx and set the nonce manually. See on these links how:
(For fetching nonce) https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactioncount
(For building tx) https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction

Comment: @Gabriel G. I mentioned that I set a higher nonce on the 2nd tx

Answer (score 2):

As of December 2019 at least, it doesn't seem possible to do this. Read this [discussion](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1202732088136351744) on Twitter for more details.

The best option is to chain the promises, as Ismael suggested in the comment above.

```js
createTokenApprovalTx().then(() => createFooTx());
```